# List group not working inside panel (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootswatch

As the title says, I was trying to make a project where the user can select an item from the side and info shows up.

Although this seems really simple, I tried doing this inside a panel like in the jsfiddle linked below but for some unknown reason it breaks. You can no longer hover and it has a darker background, I figured I made a simple mistake so I made a mock up site just to test this with very bare information so you didn't have to go through hundreds of lines of code.

Here is is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUQkd/) as you can see there is no mistakes yet this doesn't work... I was thinking maybe its just a bug and if so could someone specify a fix? I'm using bootswatch darkly theme for my css

(Ignore this just code from jsfiddle to make stackoverflow happy)

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>This doesn't work!</h1>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel primary</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
            Cras justo odio
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            Dapibus ac facilisis in
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            Morbi leo risus
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <h1>This does work!</h1>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
        Cras justo odio
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Dapibus ac facilisis in
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Morbi leo risus
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
```

also the actual links are clickable and work in both cases just no hover effect

Fix was simple as I thought it would be:

```
`<style type="text/css">
a.list-group-item:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working.

On `:focus` and `:hover` the `a.list-group-item` is changing its `background-color` from `#303030` to `transparent`.

This allows the background colour behind the item to show through. In the second case, that background colour is `#222` (coming from `body` element.)

In the first case, that background colour is `#303030` (coming from `.panel`) -- which means it is exactly the same colour as the pre-hovered `a.list-group-item`, so it looks like the hover isn't doing anything.

However, it does work.

If you're after a different colour, you're going to have to start customising bootstrap yourself, to get the colours you want.

Comment: Ahh I tried using another class .hover1:hover { background-color: blue; } just to test and that didn't work so I assumed it was a bug, thanks for this information I'll go test it now and either mark as complete or comment again.

Comment: `<style type="text/css">
    a.list-group-item:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>` fixed it thanks updated post for future people.